# Is it safe to ignore the warning in ethers.js docs about refreshing on a network change for gnosis safe apps?

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe

The `ethers.js` documentation suggests [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/best-practices/#best-practices) that dapps automatically refresh the page whenever the network changes (e.g., gorli -> mainnet). When building a safe app using `safe-apps-react-sdk` and `safe-apps-provider`, is this handled automatically by the safe context?

When I look at the official [Gnosis Safe React Apps repo](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react-apps) I don't see any code to refresh the page on a network change. I do, however, see a few custom hooks, (e.g. the one in [siwe-delegate-manager](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react-apps/blob/34c36c580300672c6366ad2d534de0a3b1534058/apps/siwe-delegate-manager/src/store/safeWalletContext.tsx#L39)) to update the web3 provider when the `sdk` or `safe` changes, which seem to contain network data.

Can I safely ignore this warning in the `ethers.js` docs and follow a similar pattern to reactively change providers/signers/networks?

Answer (score 0):

Safe Wallets are smart contract wallets, this means that your Safe wallet is only available in one chain.

If you are implementing Safe Wallet support in you Dapp, you should prevent network changes if the connected address is a Safe (you can do something like hiding the network selector).

See CowSwap Dapp as an example:

- Loaded as a Safe App in the Safe UI: https://app.safe.global/gor:0xc25519c371E1D297d784Bdc82536Dd200d844D27/apps?appUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fswap.cow.fi%2F
- Loaded as a normal Dapp using an EOA like Metamask: https://swap.cow.fi/